# How to send pre-formatted HTML elements from a WebMethod to jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql

The title sort of explains what I'm trying to do.
The reason for this is that I am trying to implement infinite scrolling on my ASP.NET C# Website. I've previous accomplished the "effect" of lazy scrolling with the `ListView` Control but that was a dirty and 'slow' trick that used a `DataPager` and a couple of `HiddenFields`.

I would like to send a completely pre-formatted HTML element from a `WebMethod` to `jQuery` so that I can append it on the container `<div>`.

Actually what I need rendered in the `WebMethod` is a bunch of objects inside a container `<div>` that are similiar to the Facebook Wall. What I previous had was a `ListView` (B) nested in another `ListView` (A). A Single Each `<ItemTemplate>` from a single ListView had multiple `ListViewItems` of the other  `ListView`. (A) Representing a wall post  and (B) Comments bound to the Primary Key of (A).

Anyway, am I looking at this issue from the right corner or should I figure out some other way of doing this? Please share you thoughts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return a string from your webmethod with the html in it - and then pump it directly into an html element on your page on the 'success' function. NB I think this is the 'html()' element - or you can use .append(text);

Using JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#Result").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetHTMLFormatted",
      data: "{}",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").html(msg.d); // or .append(msg.d);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

A better way to do it though is to return a JSON structure and use a template library to emit your html structure. See http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx

Comment: FYI: jQuery templates are no more.  JSRender is the replacement:  http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/11/09/goodby-jquery-templates-hello-jsrender.aspx

Comment: .tmpl() is not developed anymore. A new (jquery-ui) plugin, based on render.js, shall be available soon. There are other template plugins too (mustache, pure, etc...)

Comment: Exactly what I needed guys, great info. Thank you for sharing! ;) - EDIT: I was also looking for ways of doing this and did not know about the StringBuilder class. I guess this will also make things faster and smarter.